# create list in excel based upon specific cells by pulling data from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a list based upon a matrix template from multiple sheets within the same workbook. 
I've got a grid that looks like the below:

A1   Expert

A2   Intermediate

A3   Foundation

B4   Grade 1

C4   Grade 2

D4   Grade 3

So if the word "completed" is in cell B3 for instance, then the person has completed Foundation grade 1.

This will be the same template with a new worksheet for each person. The front worksheet needs to have an option to search who has completed what grade. For instance, "Bruce Wayne" sheet name has the word "completed" in cell C2 in his grid (so he has completed grade 2 intermediate") and when I search on the front worksheet for grade 2 intermediates to find out who has this, Bruce Wayne will appear in a list (along with anyone else who has that grade showing "completed" on their worksheet)

I know how to make a macro button, i know how to make a data validation list, 
and I've found a macro to loop through all worksheets (https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook)

What I don't know is how to get it to return the sheet name (bruce wayne) to form a list on the front page of names rather than just the value (completed/in progress etc) and what is the simplest way to report it:

1.create a button for each grade/level option that populates the list of sheet names (that would total 9 buttons in this example)

2. create 2 drop-down list boxes, one with Grades and one with levels and then say if grade 1 and foundation are selected from the drop-down list then it populates the sheet names in another column next to them.
3. The tab name is created from a "rename sheet" macro which works fine:
   https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2905-excel-rename-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html

   so it doesn't necessarily have to report back the sheet name, it could just report back a separate cell that dictates the sheet name if that's easier.

I'm more confused after typing that than I was before! Can anyone understand this/help me?!

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

If worksheets ("OVERVIEW") GOTO C5="Grade 1" And E5="Foundation" Then

' I want this bit to say if the overview worksheet cell C5 contains grade 1 and cell e5 contains foundation then
```

'

```
  =IF E13="completed", THEN ActiveSheet.Name = Range("I5:I11").Copy)
 ' I want this bit to then say if the word completed is present in cell E13 on any of the subsequent sheets it should copy the sheet name to the overview sheet in cells I5 to I11'


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `worksheet` object has a `Name` property in VBA, which can be accessed. [Check out the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx)

If you need more specific help, please post code.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is totally wrong, I'm new to VBA (only been using it for the last 2 weeks of my job, usually I just record a macro and assign a button!)

Comment: Sub LoopThroughSheets()

If worksheets ("OVERVIEW") GOTO C5="Grade 1" And E5="Foundation" Then

' I want this bit to say if the overview worksheet cell C5 contains grade 1 and cell e5 contains foundation then
'


 =IF E13="completed", THEN ActiveSheet.Name = Range("I5:I11").Copy)
 ' I want this bit to then say if the word completed is present in cell E13 on any of the subsequent sheets it should copy the sheet name to the overview sheet in cells I5 to I11'
 
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        
         
    Next ws
End Sub